# Python turtle screen freezing after updating to Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, macos-monterey

I'm just trying to do some of my 100 days of code homework, but since my OS upgraded last night, whenever I try to run a turtle screen (the same code that worked yesterday), the window freezes and I have to shut it down.

Everything ( to my knowledge ) is upgraded and updated in the virtual environment and my computer. ( I use homebrew ). Same freezing screen when code is ran in Idle,pycharm, visual studio code, etc.

Googling around it seems to me an OS issue, has anyone found a workaround? I've tried everything I can find to fix it, but nothing is working. I can't even get an error code because the window freezes and I have to force it to close.

Should I just go back to the last update when everything was working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I use a Mac with Monterey, working on the 100 days challenge and have the same problem.
I did not try to use Turtle with other OS.

I solved half of the problem, by going into Python-Preferences-iPhython Console-Graphics and changing graphics backend to Tkinter.

Now the page does not freeze anymore at the beginning, it opens the screen, executes the code and then when I close the screen I find another frozen screen behind which I can exit only by Force Quit.